# how to create a matrix whose elements are vectors in numpy?

Tags: numpy

for instance, assume

a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
this is read by default as a 2x2 matrix.
but is there anything I can do to make python read it as row, whose elements are vectors [1,2] and [3,4] ?

Comment: Can you give some context why you would want that ?

Comment: @Psidom basically i am writing a program to simulate some variables over time and graph them. such a matrix would be handy to store that values and graph them on matpyplot. i have no idea if it is feasible though.

Comment: Can't you just create a list of lists for that ?

Comment: @Psidom problem is that in this case I would have to manually create a lot of them. still I guess I will try figure out a different way to run the program. thanks for the help